# ubuntu does not boot properly after installation Ubuntu Server 22

Tags: boot, server, 22.04

I have an HP Proliant dl380 Server

I installed Ubuntu server and it went fine, but on startup it hangs at
[ 364.091734]

The font is also as I am used to with other installations.

Someone like that can help? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you expect anyone to be able to help, you should include some logs or error messages in your question.

Comment: Usually the line it stops at is not the issue. Look for errors in previous lines. Line number does mean anything as every system loads different drivers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)